# Render PDF Pages as SVG in canvas

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs, pdf.js

I was trying to render PDF using pdfjs. I did this fine but now I want PDF pages must be clear while zoom as well. Please review & let me knoe How I can import PDF pages as SVG to maintain clarity. Any other alternative to maintain clarity of pages would be highly appreciated

My Code

```
     __PDF_DOC.getPage(page_no).then(function (page) {
        pdfPage = page;
        var canvas1 = document.getElementById('c');

        var scale_required = 1;//__CANVAS.width / page.getViewport(1).width;

        // Get viewport of the page at required scale
        var viewport = page.getViewport(canvas.width / page.getViewport(1.0).width);


        renderContext = {
            canvasContext: canvas.getContext(),//__CANVAS_CTX,
            viewport: viewport,//viewport,

        };

        // Render the page contents in the canvas
        page.render(renderContext).then(function () {

            var bg = canvas1.toDataURL("image/svg",1);

            canvas.setBackgroundImage(bg, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
 canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Comment: If you are zooming you will need to re-render the content each time you zoom and set the viewport to the location you are zooming at.